# C++ Linker Errors (LNK 2019: unresolved external symbol) / Project Specific

Tags: c++, linked-list, linker-errors, visual-studio-debugging, lnk2019

### Main Issue

I am trying to build a homework project involving linked lists and some custom classes, but when I build the project, I get the following 3 linker errors...

```
1>customerImp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class linkedListType<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$linkedListType@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall customerType::printRentedVideo(void)" (?printRentedVideo@customerType@@QAEXXZ)
1>testVideoStore.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class linkedListType<class videoType> const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$linkedListType@VvideoType@@@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>testVideoStore.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class linkedListType<class customerType> const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$linkedListType@VcustomerType@@@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

I've done a lot of programming, but have never run across linker errors until now, so I'm having trouble deciphering and debugging the errors. I've put a zip file with the original source code as well as the Solution File with the "built" project in my public DropBox at the link below. I am using Visual Studio 2012 on 64-bit Windows 8 computer. Build Specs are set to Debug / Win32 platform.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/101002796/Rinehart-P07v2.zip

#### ADDITIONAL NOTES:

- The majority of the source is book source, and doesn't seem to have errors
- No thoughts from the instructor. He was as clueless as I was
- I've tried building in a Windows 7 Dev environment with no luck.
- I've tried adding all implementations to the header files, still same errors
- I've tried many other solution steps from forums/blogs/etc, but nada worked

Quick help would be appreciated as I have a huge stack of Calculus to finish up before this programming project is due, I work part-time, and am married (married people should understand), so nasty little debugging issues like this are a bane on productivity.

Thanks a million in advance,
~Sean R.

Comment: Not sure if this works or not, but *bump*... It's a little past due, and I got most of the credit, but can grab those extra points if I can fix these errors. Thanks, ~Sean